# Why are social tags half functional in my Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm migrating a SharePoint 2007 farm to SharePoint 2010. In the page header in 2010, I see a button for "Tags and Notes", but the "I Like" button is missing (though there is an empty space where it should be). When I click the "Tags and Notes" button, it pops up a modal window with space to add a note, but no tagging abilities are available. I haven't changed any of the social ribbon code, it's all OOTB. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are aware of the new Service Application Architecture of SharePoint 2010. The "I Like" and "Tags and Notes" services are part of following Service Applications:

"Managed Metadata" Service Application - I like, Tagging in Page Header

"User Profile Service Application" - Notes in Page header

The association between your Web Application and Service Application is configured in Central Administration.

Here is what you may want to do:

**Make sure both service applications are running and configured and then associate Managed Metadata service with your Web application to see "I Like" and Tagging in the Page Header.**

Comment: Hmm. I thought all the social features were under User Profile Services, but I see I was mistaken. I'll have to enable the Managed Metadata Services. Thanks!